# What is the difference between Shonen'ai, JUNE, Yaoi and Boys' love?

Tags: terminology

The difference between Shonen'ai and Yaoi [as already been asked](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/what-is-the-difference-between-yuri-and-shoujo-ai-yaoi-and-shounen-ai-and-ecchi/).

However, I encountered a few more terminologies concerning anime and mangas referring to masculine homosexuality :

- Shōnen'ai
- JUNE
- Yaoi
- Boys' love

What are the main differences between those genres?

Comment: Boy's Love is, like Girl's Love in Shoujo Ai/Yuri, just another way to describe Shounen Ai/Yaoi.....though i have never seen the term JUNE before

Comment: @Makoto why is this a duplicate?

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade:  The duplicate has answers which cover most (if not all) of this terminology.  The fact that a magazine name came up does make the answer *below* more relevant, but by and large I still believe this to be answered well by the existing question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Shounen-Ai** 
Literally translated means boys love. However, in these type of series, it usually represents an innocent, non sexual nature of homosexuality.
Ex- 7-Ghosts.

(Taken from wikipedia)

> The term shōnen-ai (boy love) originally connoted ephebophilia or pederasty in Japan, but from the early 1970s to the late 1980s, was used to describe a new genre of shōjo manga, primarily produced by the Year 24 Group of women authors, about beautiful boys in love. Characteristics of shōnen-ai include exoticism, often taking place in Europe, and idealism. Jeffrey Angles particularly notes Moto Hagio's The Heart of Thomas (1974) and Keiko Takemiya's Kaze to Ki no Uta (1976-1984) as being groundbreaking, noting their portrayal of intense friendship between males, including jealousy and desire.

**June**- This name actually comes from a specific manga magazine and it cannot be said as a genre or demographic per se.

(From Wikipedia)

> A manga or text story with male homosexual themes for women written in an aesthetic (耽美 tanbi) style, named for the Juné magazine.

**Yaoi**

> Yaoi (/ˈjaʊi/, Japanese: [ja.o.i]), also known as Boys' Love (BL), is a Japanese genre of fictional media focusing on romantic or sexual relationships between male characters, typically aimed at a female audience and usually created by female authors. Although yaoi is typically aimed at a female audience, the genre also attracts some male readers; however, manga aimed at a gay male audience (bara) is considered a separate genre.

**Boys Love**

Yaoi and Boys-Love are basically the same thing and can be used interchangeably

Answer (score 1):

Shonen-ai (shonen = boy, ai = love), so it's boy's love.
Yaoi is mostly just the physical side of the relationship between male characters.

June is the earliest yaoi (BL) magazine.
BL means boy x boy relationships.